# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

When I check maven Version

```
$ mvn -version

Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
```

How to solve it ?
these are my java jdk version.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)


$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Comment: Run the command `which java` and report back the result.

Comment: Maybe you need to add $JAVA_HOME/bin to your PATH

Comment: Maybe run `which -a java` just to list all possibilities.

Comment: @zero298which -a java
/usr/bin/java

Comment: Setting up the environment for Java can be a pain.  It can be different per user and per system.  I often create a shell script to launch my java app that ensures the environment is set up correctly.  This has the added advantage that instead of launching it with "java -jar myapp.jar" you can start it with "myapp" like nearly every other type of app on the face of the planet.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME variable is set to the JRE folder, like this:

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre`

To further improve your setup, you can let Java pick the correct version by putting this in your JAVA_HOME (this assumes you used the Oracle installer):

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

If this doesn't work for you, make sure permissions are set correctly (Execute permissions on the binaries)